# MSAccess 2010 VBA Open a read-only database

Tags: vba, ms-access, readonly

I have a MSAccess database that I'm trying to pull archived data into, from other MSAccess databases that live in read-only folders.
So ...

```
Dim aidbx As DAO.Database
Dim stDB as STring
 stDB = 'path to read-only database
...
Set aidbx = OpenDatabase(stDB, False, True)
```

So it craters right there, even though the 'True' is telling it to open the database read-only.  I get the 'Run time error 3050 - could not lock file' error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried setting a read-only folder, and the folder is not read-only, the files in the folder are read-only. I tested your code and don't get error. It is possible to pull data from another db without a connection object variable and without actually opening the other db. What do you want to do, INSERT into existing table or new table?

Comment: No, I just want to extract some data.  I have similar code that runs in excel, and it doesn’t have this problem.  But it uses an ADODB connection, and I’m note sure how to do that in Access.

Comment: Why not use ADODB connection and ADODB recordset in the Access code? Why use DAO recordset? See answer for possible alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know how to set ADODB connection since you have that in Excel code. Should be able to use the same in Access VBA. Example using early binding so need to set reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library`:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='C:\Users\June\Sample.accdb'"
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Table1", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Following is example of opening a DAO database and recordset objects in a DAO workspace which apparently is not supported after Access 2013:

```
Dim DAOws As DAO.Workspace
Dim DAOdb As DAO.Database
Dim DAOrs As DAO.Recordset
Set DAOws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set DAOdb = DAOws.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\June\Sample.accdb")
Set DAOrs = DAOdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Example using DAO database and recordset objects but not workspace:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\June\Sample.accdb")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")
```

Access VBA can open a recordset object that pulls data from another database without connection and other database object variables by using the CurrentDb object and IN operator. Example:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 IN 'C:\Users\June\Sample.accdb'")
```

Here is a test of last approach using SQL with JOIN:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Submit.*, [103].* 
         FROM Submit INNER JOIN [103] ON Submit.LabNum=[103].LabNum
         IN 'C:\Users\June\Sample.accdb'", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Any of these methods can reference a query instead of table as source.

Comment: Hi - your last example does indeed work - thank-you!  However, I have a much longer query that involves several tables and inner joins etc, and I can't figure out the syntax for including the IN operator.  Will this work with multiple tables in the remote database?

Comment: Probably not. Likely have to use other option. I was able to pull from a query located in the backend.

Comment: Actually, just gave it a test and JOIN did work. See revised answer. Do a test with your more complex query.

Comment: Hey!  I think its working!  I need to check what it returns, but at least it connects and doesnt puke!  The last part that was messing me up was  ORDER BY which, turns out, has to go at the very end after the filename (not just before).  Thank-you so much for taking the time to post these answers.  Beer for you!

Comment: Glad to help. I learned a lot in the process. Be sure to mark as answer if it really does work as needed.