# Make Table SQL Query with Parameters in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create an SQL query in Excel VBA that would create a table in Access based on parameters of a cell in Excel. Usually I could use an execute query to run a pre-built query in the database but since I need to modify it based on the parameters entered into a cell I need to do it this way. The parameter would only be for the Where criteria. For this example we can say that it is also selecting the fixed fields "Sales" and "Product" and the "Where" field is "Model." I also will need to delete the existing table with the same name since I ran into an error that the table already existed. What would the VBA code look like for this?

```
Step 1: Delete table with the same name
Step 2: Create a new table in Access with the "Where" criteria pointing to a cell.
```

```
Sub CreateTable()
On Error GoTo SubError
    Const DbLoc As String = "C:\Folder to Excel\Database1.accdb"
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim recCount As Long
    Dim SQL As String


    Set xlBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)


    Set db = OpenDatabase(DbLoc)

    SQL = "SELECT Sales, Product " & _
    "FROM Table1 " & _
    "WHERE Model IN (1, 2);"
```

If I can feed the parameters to an existing make table query I would happy too!

Comment: Do provide some samples. For example how would excel columns look like, what queries you expect to create (if 'Create Table' then what about data type)

Comment: More than one way to approach. Could repeatedly create and delete table/query. In VBA it would be `DoCmd.DeleteObject …`. But doing that from Excel may be difficult. Or could just delete and insert records. Then probably don't even need query. If you want VBA in Excel to manipulate objects in Access, need to establish a connection to Access. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954404/msaccess-2010-vba-open-a-read-only-database/54962238#54962238. With this connection, can run SQL actions (DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE). Why do you need to code in Excel?

Comment: *Usually I could use an execute query to run a pre-built query in the database but since I need to modify it based on the parameters*... you are aware you can parameterize stored queries in Access?

Comment: @GRO I have added an example of my code. I need to know how to turn this into a create query for access.

Comment: @Parfait. The issue is that I need to change the parameters based on what is in a cell in excel. If they were fixed parameters then I could just use an execute query.

Comment: With QueryDefs you can pass *any* parameter into a query. Why do you want to create separate tables for select models? What is the end goal?

Comment: @Parfait Thanks. I should use QueryDefs. How do I do this?

Comment: Once again what is end goal? Why recreate tables each time?

Comment: And again, deleting and inserting records would be easier. And why is Excel even involved? Don't see a way for Excel to pass parameters to an Access query object.