# Error in visual basic statement with Jet statement on Workspace.openDatabase

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a .accdb file at Path ("C:\Southern\Southern.accdb") and recordset shows "Run Time Error 3734" at Workspace.openDatabase statement. I am trying the following code-

```
ChDir "C:\Southern"
    Me!F_Main1.SourceObject = "F_Blank"
    Me!F_Main1.Requery

    Me!CurrentDate = Now()
    Me!CurrentTime = Now()

    '      Check the startup record to find the shop

    Dim Jet As Workspace
    Dim PowerShop As Database
    Dim StartRS As Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim ReadOnly As Boolean
    Dim NetPath As String




    ReadOnly = True


    '      >>>>> Open Database <<<<<

    Set Jet = CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
    MsgBox "Opening Database...."
    Set PowerShop = Jet.OpenDatabase("C:\Southern\Southern.accdb", ReadOnly)

    'C:\Southern
    '       >>>> Read Thru BuyStocks for this buy

    SQL = "Select Shop from T_Startup"
```

I have an error in the following statement-

```
Set PowerShop = Jet.OpenDatabase("C:\Southern\Southern.accdb", ReadOnly)
```

Please guide to solve the error

Comment: I have never seen Jet and Workspace used like this. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954404/msaccess-2010-vba-open-a-read-only-database/54962238#54962238

Comment: @June7 Can you correct me that which statement have a problem. I am new with Jet Statment Use. Thanks

Comment: Did you review the link? It shows how to connect to another db file. It even shows methods of pulling data from another database without a connection object. Follow referenced link and pick a method.